# Confirm changes and additions to sql database via php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have a input form where people can add data about media to the SQL database via web. My question is - is there a way to confirm all the added data?

Example:

Unknown person fills out the form with spam and presses the submit button, I get a message about (or must confirm) the information before it is send to the sql database.

Comment: This thing can be implemented using a staging table where you stage the data for processing such as decision making.

Answer (score 0):

If you are properly building your SQL inserts such that you are protected against SLQ injection, etc., and your goal is to moderate the content, then this is as simple as adding a column to your table called "confirmed" with a default value of "0".  Your viewing functions are then checking this value (if $confirmed)...) and no input is viewable until after you've set the confirmed flag.  You can delete during moderation or even have a garbage collector cron job that deletes unconfirmed entries older than a preset time.

If you are doing this because you're worried about data getting into your database that can corrupt the database (SQL injection and other nefarious problems), then moderating the input is a very time-consuming solution.  You should read up on [preparing queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to avoid these problems.

Answer (score 0):

There's three basic options here depending on your particular needs.

Insert into the table with a conditional flag that needs to be set by "confirming" the entries. This requires periodically purging unconfirmed entries after some amount of grace time, typically a day, to avoid cluttering up data with garbage. This can make searching difficult as you'll have to include this flag in all indexes in order to maintain performance and avoid showing non-confirmed data.

The second option is to take all the parameters, package them up as either a singular JSON injected in a hidden field, or each element rendered as a hidden field with identical names from the previous submission. The confirmation process will then re-post these parameters with an additional "confirmed" step.

The third option is to do this all client-side using JavaScript, jQuery, or some kind of front-end framework like Angular or React. This avoids the round-trip to the server, and the server does not have to do any additional work to verify that things are confirmed.